# Magento 2: How to define Order of Events?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, xml, custom, sort

In my `events.xml` I have so 4-5 Observer With Events. I would like to Define Their Call Order

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch_module_myModule_postform">
            <observer name="captcha_post_form" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\CheckCustomFormObserver" />
        </event>
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch_skip_shoppingcart">
            <observer name="skip_shopping_cat_page" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\SkipShoppingCartObserver" />
        </event>
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
            <observer name="check_shopping_cart_page" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\CheckCartObserver" />
        </event>
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index">
            <observer name="check_shopping_cart_page" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\CheckShoppingCartProductObserver" />
        </event>
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
            <observer name="check_login_persistent" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\CheckLoginPersistentObserver" />
        </event>
     </config>
```

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

As i referred above Doc. There will be no SortOrder which i can define event wise. I know each gonna call on Different Events Still can? Any Idea? Can we define Dependancy that on basis of OutPut of 1st Event 2nd or 3rd Event will be called? From 1st Observer, if result is true then call 2nd. If false then call 3rd?

What is purpose of `name`, because we never use anywhere. Is it for developer purpose only?

Comment: Instead of calling all events from events.xml, call only first event in events.xml file which is always going to be triggered. Now in the observer function do your operation and check the conditions and fire other events based on your conditional checks.

Comment: Ok so how can i put condition for say event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index` in Observer?

Comment: In the first observer function check the actions fired . For reference here is something similar explained for Magento 1 https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/using-controller-observer-dispatch-event

Comment: @amitshree It's for Magento 1, but Helpful